# Passing variable between blocks in Openresty/Lua with ngx.ctx

Tags: nginx, lua, http-headers, openresty

Trying to pass a variable between two lua blocks. Supposedly, this should work with ngx.ctx, like this:

```
header_filter_by_lua_block  {
ngx.ctx.myvar = ngx.header["X-fetch"];
}

access_by_lua_block  {
ngx.header["X-send"] = ngx.ctx.myvar;
}
```

but it doesn't. What's wrong?

P.S. Testing with both in one block does work (basically duplicating the existing header, but this is just for illustration)

```
header_filter_by_lua_block  {
ngx.ctx.myvar = ngx.header["X-fetch"];
ngx.header["X-send"] = ngx.ctx.myvar;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `access_by_lua_block` runs before `header_filter_by_lua_block`.

Take a look at https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/

Comment: Indeed, apparently I was expecting that it'd only be the order of code... Any chance to have it run after?

Comment: ( Tried doing it in `log_by_lua_block` but it doesn' work )

Comment: You mean make `access_by_lua_block ` run after `header_filter_by_lua_block`? No you cannot change the order of directive execution. Why not use a different directive that does run after?

Comment: Because the first thing I want to do only works in `header_filter_by_lua` while the other doesn't work in `body_filter_by_lua`. Ended up taking a completely different approach.

Comment: @LucianDavidescu you also just do `add_header X-Send ngx.var.http_x_fetch`. Why do you want to store the header from one variable to another? All request headers are available as `ngx.var.http_*`

Comment: I was trying to set info from the CMS (via a response header) and have openresty send it away to another server. In the end it was more convenient to write it to a json file and just pick it up from there.

Comment: @LucianDavidescu maybe post your entire solution - I have a feeling you may be over-engineering it.

Comment: Well, since I took a different approach, the solution is not really relevant to the question, but here it goes, in brief: I need to pass content-specific information (title, author, section) to the webserver for server-side analytics via measurement protocol. Headers set from the CMS were one possible vehicle, but I ran into this egg-or-chicken problem. So, instead, I chose to have the CMS write separate json files, which openresty can read just fine inside a single `access_by_lua_block` and then post them away. This way it's also much easier with caching.